# Intel HD 5500 support on ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I am searching for a new laptop these days, with an intel i5. But around 95 % of them have intel hd 5500 graphics. By making a simple google search for it I can find a dozen of incompatibility problems with ubuntu (e.g. https://bugs.launchpad.net/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1432194)

Should I go on and choose one of them despite these problems, hoping that on 15.10 with the latest kernel, many of them will be diminished. or search for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, I have bought it and both ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10 work out of the box with this gpu.