# How can i get a Intel HD 5500 graphics driver for linux OSes?

Tags: intel

I got a Dell Inspiron 14 3443 laptop containing Intel HD 5500 graphics but it's driver is not available for any linux OS(couldn't find on google). I am very passionate to install linux. But, without it, the brightness is maximum and can't be controlled. Please help me know how can i get the driver for linux or what should i do? Or, please make me clear if i'll be able to get that driver for linux or not?

Comment: There is no separate driver for this adapter. Regarding the brightness there are lots of solutions.

Answer (score 4):

First it sounds as if you are new to Ubuntu / Linux , but generally the driver for your graphics card is in the kernel and thus installed already.

Second, if you do need to install a driver it is best to use the packages available from the repositories in your distro.

for Ubuntu see - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

If there is a package you need not in the repositories, you then try a ppa or, IMHO, build from source.

There are various reports regarding your video card

Works - [Intel HD 5500 support on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682655/intel-hd-5500-support-on-ubuntu)
Bugs - https://bugs.launchpad.net/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1432194

So, have you tried Ubuntu ? Did you actually have a problem ? If you did, you would need to file / follow a bug report and/or contact Intel for a driver as is is a 3rd party proprietary (closed source) driver.

So to some extent your question is quite broad as you are asking about all distros, and not just ubuntu, and we do not know if you are even having a problem or not.

To be honest, as with any OS, it is best to either purchase a computer with Linux (Ubuntu) pre installed (same as you did with windows) or purchase a Linux compatible video card. You would have the same problem if you tried running a windows incompatible video card in windows.